# Travis CI - android build failed. No connected devices error

Tags: java, android, git, continuous-integration, travis-ci

Trying to get started with Travis CI for my Android projects but Travis still failing while build my android project.

Reason:

```
:app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.

> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Link to travis:
https://travis-ci.org/hypeapps/Episodie/builds/158706530

.travis.yml:

```
language: android
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
before_install:
- chmod +x gradlew
env:
  global:
   - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=24
   - EMULATOR_API_LEVEL=21
   - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=24.0.1
   - ANDROID_ABI=google_apis/armeabi-v7a
   - ADB_INSTALL_TIMEOUT=20 # minutes (2 minutes by default)
android:
  components:
    - tools
    - tools
    - platform-tools
    - build-tools-$ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION
    - android-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL
    - android-$EMULATOR_API_LEVEL
    - extra
    - add-on
    - extra-google-m2repository
    - extra-android-m2repository

    # Google Play Services
    - extra-google-google_play_services
    # Support library
    - extra-android-support

    - addon-google_apis-google-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL
    - addon-google_apis-google-$EMULATOR_API_LEVEL

    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-addon-google_apis-google-$ANDROID_API_LEVEL
    - sys-img-armeabi-v7a-addon-google_apis-google-$EMULATOR_API_LEVEL
  licenses:
    - 'android-sdk-preview-license-52d11cd2'
    - 'android-sdk-license-.+'
    - 'google-gdk-license-.+'
  before_script:
     - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:"$EMULATOR_API_LEVEL --abi $ANDROID_ABI
     - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
     - android-wait-for-emulator
```

Link to gradle file:
[build.gradle](https://github.com/hypeapps/Episodie/blob/master/app/build.gradle)

Github project:
[GitHub](https://github.com/hypeapps/Episodie/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is:

add line on top:

```
sudo: false
```

Create Emulator Management: Create, Start and Wait

```
before_script:
  - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t android-21 --abi armeabi-v7a
  - emulator -avd test -no-skin -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
```

Now Travis CI works.

Comment: can I ask a question, why?